# Silent Process Exit due to KiSchedulerApcTerminate

Tags: windows, kernel

I have a Windows 10 machine where some UI process runs happily for days until it silently exits without any visible exception. 
I have enabled ETW tracing but pretty much all call stacks come up with ???? marks. I suppose there was no proper ETW provider rundown happening in this process. After enabling Process Destruction call stacks I have found that one

```
[Root] 
 ntoskrnl.exe!KiPageFault 
 ntoskrnl.exe!KiInitiateUserApc 
 ntoskrnl.exe!KiDeliverApc 
 ntoskrnl.exe!KiSchedulerApcTerminate 
 ntoskrnl.exe!PsExitCurrentUserThread 
 ntoskrnl.exe!PspExitThread 
 ntoskrnl.exe!PspExitProcess
```

Does this indicate a page in error so I should suspect a hardware failure of the hard disc or memory?

I have found a failed file io request at that time:

```
The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device.
    (0xc0000010) = Event SubType, FSCTL = Event Type, C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
```

which makes me think that the hard disk has an issue.